# How to assign multiple database variables to one request variable in SpringBoot Web Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, post

I a trying to create a SpringBoot web service with Rest, I am querying database as;

`jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT first_name" + ", last_name" + ", email" + ",  city" + " from PERSON + "where  first_name=?" + "and last_name=?"`

and I created a class in service with exact variable names to match with the database variables.

But instead of using first_name and last_name as a request parameters, I want to use them together as "first_name-last_name". So i created a variable called "fullName" and split this string variable in "Controller" class as;

```
String [] variables = getFullName().split("-");
String first_name = variables[0];
String last_name = variables[1];
```

But I couldn't figure out how can I fill the values from database after splitting. Can you assist me ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way is to use `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate#query(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[], org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor<T>)` method and pass the array of parameter, that in you case is exactly `variables`. Just remember to create a `ResultSetExtractor` implementation to transform the ResultSet in yout wanted output

here's the thing ( I used the `Student` class that I already had ready )

```
public List<Student> serviceMethodWithQuestionMarkNotation(String fullName) {
        // others
        String[] strings = fullName.split("-");

//        String first_name = strings[0];
//        String last_name = strings[1];
        // others
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE first_Name = ? AND last_Name = ?";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, strings, new StudentResultSetExtractorImpl());
    }

 private static class StudentResultSetExtractorImpl implements ResultSetExtractor<List<Student>> {
        @Override
        public List<Student> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Student student = new Student();
                student.setId(rs.getString("id"));
                student.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
                student.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
                students.add(student);
            }
            return students;
        }
    }
```